# What causes the segmentation fault in the doubly linked list code

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

When printList is called the following code causes a segmentation fault. Why is this?

A working example of the failure is at https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/ZeqrQf9esb

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node * next;
    Node * prev;
};

void addNode(struct Node **head_ref,int pos,int data)
{
    struct Node*nn=new Node;
    int k=0;
    nn->data=data;
    if(*head_ref==nullptr)
        *head_ref=nn;
    else
    {
        struct Node*temp=*head_ref;

        while(k<pos)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }

        if(temp->next!=nullptr)
        {

            nn->prev=temp;
            nn->next=temp->next;
            temp->next=nn;
            nn->next->prev=nn;


        }
        else
        {
            nn->next=nullptr;
            nn->prev=temp;
            temp->next=nn;
        }
    }
}
 void printList(struct Node *Node)
    {
      struct Node *temp=Node;
      //goto end
      while(temp->next!=NULL)
      {
        temp=temp->next;
      }
      //goto start
      while(temp->prev!=NULL)
      {
       temp = temp->prev;
      }
      //now print
      while(temp!=NULL)
      {
          printf("%d ",temp->data);
          temp=temp->next;
      }

    }

int main()
{
    Node * head; 
    addNode(&head,0,10);
    addNode(&head,0,11);
    addNode(&head,0,12);


    std::cerr << head->data << std::endl;
    std::cerr << head->next->data << std::endl;
    std::cerr << head->next->next-> data << std::endl;  
      printList(head);
}
```

Comment: This code cannot be "run" Please include a complete example include a main function to show how you are using it.

Comment: Ideally make it so that the code can be pasted to https://wandbox.org/ and it will run and demostrate your error.

Comment: I just included the entire code including the main function @bradgonesurfing

Comment: You could start by simplifying the code and starting with a few simple cases. For example I have done for you https://wandbox.org/permlink/N5MUzCDzEuGjNJoh which doesn't cause a segmentation fault. Then build up your test cases until you find the problem.

Comment: Ok. You now have a verifiable segmentation fault. See https://wandbox.org/permlink/9k91JSQuQm68Ujgm Next time you know how to ask a question. ;)

Comment: But please change your example so that it is not processing standard input. using scanf. Set up a fixed test case so that you can demonstrate to people here exactly what you are running.

Comment: And why are you mixing cin and scanf? Did you write this code?

Comment: Yes it doesn't cause a segmentation fault until we don't include a function to print the linked list.When I included the printList function it again showed the segmentation fault.Here is the link for it-https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/ZeqrQf9esb @bradgonesurfing

Comment: Thanks for the working test case. I have now resolved your problem in an answer

Comment: I also rewrote your question as an example to you how you should write questions in the future if you want answers. I was being generous with my time today. Most people are not :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and also for editing the question.But still when I tried using your code to insert after the 1st position it's showing segmentation fault.It only inserts value at the head position.Here is the link where I tried working your code-(https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/fZ2j3gMLaK) . And thanks for your valuable time :) @bradgonesurfing

Comment: Just put printf everywhere until you find out exactly where it crashes. This only works on wandbox but not on geeksforgeeks. Geeksforgeeks doesn't output anything if there is an exception.

Comment: You could also use a proper IDE like visual studio to debug it. You need to put some self effort in.

Comment: Thanks a lot I successfully got the code run without any segmentation fault :) @bradgonesurfing

Comment: Glad to be of help. Hopefully the most help I've given is not the solution but the process to help you solve it quicker next time. good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to initialize next and prev to be null. If you don't do this then they take random values. The important lines are

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node * next=nullptr;
    Node * prev=nullptr;
};
```

See https://wandbox.org/permlink/qooehizoRifrvOVX for a working example. Full code below

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node * next=nullptr;
    Node * prev=nullptr;
};

void addNode(struct Node **head_ref,int pos,int data)
{
    struct Node*nn=new Node;
    int k=0;
    nn->data=data;
    if(*head_ref==nullptr)
        *head_ref=nn;
    else
    {
        struct Node*temp=*head_ref;

        while(k<pos)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }

        if(temp->next!=nullptr)
        {

            nn->prev=temp;
            nn->next=temp->next;
            temp->next=nn;
            nn->next->prev=nn;


        }
        else
        {
            nn->next=nullptr;
            nn->prev=temp;
            temp->next=nn;
        }
    }
}
 void printList(struct Node *Node)
    {
      struct Node *temp=Node;


      //goto end
      while(temp->next!=nullptr)
      {
        temp=temp->next;
      }


      //goto start
      while(temp->prev!=nullptr)
      {
       temp = temp->prev;
      }



      //now print
      while(temp!=nullptr)
      {
          printf("%d ",temp->data);
          temp=temp->next;
      }


    }

int main()
{
    Node * head; 
    addNode(&head,0,10);
    addNode(&head,0,11);
    addNode(&head,0,12);

    std::cerr << head->data << std::endl;
    std::cerr << head->next->data << std::endl;
    std::cerr << head->next->next-> data << std::endl;  

    printList(head);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) don't mix malloc and new in the same code.  You'll lose track of which nodes came from which allocator and if you free something that came from new, or delete something that came from malloc, you have a serious bug.

2) while advancing "k" times... you forget to increment k so never stop advancing, and walk off your list.  That's a source of crashes:

```
    while(k<pos)
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
```

There may be more, but I stopped looking after seeing #2.

Comment: I added your suggested fixes to https://wandbox.org/permlink/VW6no2mZsW1TVLZZ but there is still a segv

Comment: you need to think about what happens if you want to insert into position 0 (what does it come after?  How do your replace the head?)  Also, if you request to insert at the end, is temp null?  You might want to stop this loop if temp->next is null.  Then decide if it's an error if k < pos.